How to customize the header displayed for my control library in the Visual Studio toolbox
I want to have the toolbox in Visual Studio to show a custom name for my user control library instead of the library namespace
Currently shows as next picture

I want to show
Company buttons instead of Company.UI.Controls Components
How can I do that?

To rename a tab in the Visual Studio Toolbox, you can right-click on the tab and select "Rename Tab". This action allows you to provide a new name for the tab.
References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/toolbox?view=vs-2022
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/misc/how-to-create-a-toolbox-control-that-uses-windows-forms?view=vs-2015&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2017&redirectedfrom=MSDN
